# PythonのCSVの書き込み結果を変数で受け取りたい

Tags: python, python3, csv

お世話になります。
PythonでCSVの書き込みを行い、変数に取得したいと考えています。
通常であれば、ファイルに書き込んだ後、そのファイルを読み込むことで取得可能かと思います。
例えばこんな感じで。
※ 申し訳ありませんが、例外処理とか、もろもろは省略させていただいています。）
また、今回は便宜上、データを手入力していますが、実際は利用者が入力したデータを利用する予定です。

```
import csv, tempfile
fp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="w+", newline="", encoding="utf_8", prefix="csv_", suffix=".dat")
writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
li = []
li.append("番号")
li.append("内容")
writer.writerow(li)
li = []
li.append("1")
li.append("あいうえお")
writer.writerow(li)
li = []
li.append("2")
li.append("abc")
writer.writerow(li)
fp.seek(0)
value=fp.read()
fp.close()
print(value)
```

一応これでもいいのですが、できればファイルを介さずに直接データを取得できないかと考えています。
何かいい方法があれば、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSVファイルの内容を文字列として生成したいということでしたら、`io.StringIO`を書き出し先として`csv.writer`を生成すればよいと思います。

```py
from io import StringIO
import csv
buf = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buf)
writer.writerow(["番号","内容"])
writer.writerow(["1","あいうえお"])
buf.getvalue() # ===> '番号,内容\r\n1,あいうえお\r\n'
```

Comment: お世話になります。うまくいきました。アドバイスありがとうございました。